# How to save HTML ul-li structure into javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

i have this following html structure usilg ul and li.

```
<ul class="treeview" id="productTree">
   <li class="collapsable lastCollapsable">
     <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea lastCollapsable-hitarea"></div>
     <span id="top1" class="">top1</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="collapsable lastCollapsable">
         <span class="">mod1</span>
         <ul>
           <li class="last">
              <span>bottom1</span>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="collapsable lastCollapsable">
     <span id="top2" class="">top2</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="collapsable lastCollapsable">
         <span class="">mid2</span>
           <ul>
             <li class="last">
                <span>bottom2</span>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the website allows user to add more data under this structure and am using jquery treeview to show the tree structure dynamically.
  Now i need to save this whole ul-li structure into a js object for future use in the website. how do i achieve this? the last node("bottom1 and bottom2 here") has a class "last" if that helps.
 as we can add data dynamically we can be sure how much levels of ul li is there at the end when user clicks "save"

Comment: You mean, aside from doing something like `var x = $('#productTree');` ? What exactly do you mean by "saving ul-li structure"?

Comment: Could you not just save it as a string? Or do you need to be able to access nodes of it as if it were an object?

Comment: if you want to save your data from this format use Database to save items in `child-parent mode`. in the start form load from db and after changes save them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function to save a tree object;

```
function save(obj_ul, tree){

    var obj_lis = obj_ul.find("li")

    if (obj_lis.length == 0) return;        

    obj_lis.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.parent("ul").get(0) == obj_ul.get(0))
        {
            tree.push({
                name : $this.find('> span').text(),
                child : save($this.find("ul").first(), [])
            });


        }
    });
    return tree;
}

console.log(save($('#productTree'), []));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reprouce the same thing verbatim, as a string of HTML elsewhere on the site, you could just do this? Then `.append()` or `.prepend()` `treeview` where you like.

​var treeview = $('#productTree').parent().html()

Comment: Oh yea i know what you meant. That am already doing. the fact is there is a next and previous button at the bottom of the page.on pressing either we'll navigate away from the page and when we come back again to same page the tree structure should be shown.for that am using the method suggested above. but i also need to save the whole data for some math calculation and related things.so wondering if i can save it as a js Object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want JSON:

```
function save(){
    var tmp = [];

    $('#productTree li.collapsable').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $spans = $this.find('span'),
            o = [];

            $spans.each(function(){
               o.push($(this).text())
            })

            tmp.push(o);
    });
    return tmp;
}
```

You could also use `map()` to accomplish the same thing, too.

EDIT: Updated, assuming your text will live inside a `span`. This will create an array of arrays, each containing the text from the `span`s inside each of your list-items.

Comment: The number of levels can be different and hence the code must be general