# Create JS Object from dynamically generated unordered list

Tags: javascript, php, solr, html-lists, associative-array

Most of the answer here what to go from an object to a list. I need to go the other way. Here is the HTML. This is only a subset of a much larger list - but it is always the same structure and will only ever be three levels deep.

```
<li class="group">

    <input class="group" id="Agriculture" type="checkbox" name="Agriculture">
    <label for="Agriculture">Agriculture</label>

    <ul class="categories">

        <li class="category">
            <input class="input_category" id="Apiculture" type="checkbox" name="Apiculture">
            <label for="Apiculture&quot;">Apiculture</label>
        </li>

        <li class="category">

            <input class="input_category" id="Barns & buildings" type="checkbox" name="Barns & buildings">
            <label for="Barns & buildings"="">Barns &amp; buildings</label>

            <ul class="subCategories">

                <li class="subcategory">
                    <input class="subCategory" id="Operations" type="checkbox" name="Operations">
                    <label for="Operations&quot;">Operations</label>
                </li>
                <li class="subcategory">
                    <input class="subCategory" id="Storage" type="checkbox" name="Storage">
                    <label for="Storage&quot;">Storage</label>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="category">

            <input class="input_category" id="Crop handling" type="checkbox" name="Crop handling">
            <label for="Crop" handling"="">Crop handling</label>

            <ul class="subCategories">
                <li class="subcategory">
                    <input class="subCategory" id="Harvest equipment" type="checkbox" name="Harvest equipment">
                    <label for="Harvest" equipment"="">Harvest equipment</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="category">

            <input class="input_category" id="Dairying" type="checkbox" name="Dairying">
            <label for="Dairying&quot;">Dairying</label>

            <ul class="subCategories">
                <li class="subcategory">
                    <input class="subCategory" id="Test equipment" type="checkbox" name="Test equipment">
                    <label for="Test" equipment"="">Test equipment</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="category">

            <input class="input_category" id="Land improvement" type="checkbox" name="Land improvement">
            <label for="Land" improvement"="">Land improvement</label>

            <ul class="subCategories">
                <li class="subcategory">
                    <input class="subCategory" id="Miscellaneous" type="checkbox" name="Miscellaneous">
                    <label for="Miscellaneous&quot;">Miscellaneous</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="category">
            <input class="input_category" id="Poultry equipment" type="checkbox" name="Poultry equipment">
            <label for="Poultry" equipment"="">Poultry equipment</label>
        </li>

    </ul>

</li>
```

I have tried many ideas - recursive functions, foreach loops, etc...

This answer got close ([How to save HTML ul-li structure into javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156416/how-to-save-html-ul-li-structure-into-javascript-object)) - but they resulting array is (in my opinion only) messy, and it doesn't quite do what I need.

From this new object I need to send it to a php file to create filter queries in SOLR. As all these items in the html above are associated with each other (it's a lexicon) I need to get it into an clean(ish) object so I can pass it to php which will create the queries depending on what is checked.

What I need from the object is the associations for each "branch" - this will allow me to create SOLR filter queries using booleans.

At the end of the whole process I want something like the following....

```
Agriculture => Apiculture
Agriculture => Barns & buildings
Agriculture => Barns & buildings => Operations
Agriculture => Barns & buildings => Storage
Agriculture => Crop Handling
Agriculture => Crop Handling => Harvest Equipment
Agriculture => Dairying
Agriculture => Dairying => Test Equipment
Agriculture => Land Management
Agriculture => Land Management => Miscellaneous
Agriculture => Poultry equipment
```

This way in the PHP I can create the queries with relative ease. Each these pseudo lines can be made into individual filter queries.

Any ideas welcome - even new ways to do what is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try creating the array in the input element
<input class="group" id="Agriculture" type="checkbox" name="Agriculture[]">   and <input class="input_category" id="Apiculture" type="checkbox" name="Agriculture['Apiculture']">

Comment: So in what way and where was this list "dynamically generated"?

Comment: The data comes from SOLR and created in JS before display. The list changes as the search query changes, showing only the groups and categories that are associated with the query results.